# Powershell Looping through eventlog

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, events, logging

I am trying to gather data from eventlogs of logons, disconnect, logoff etc... this data will be stored in a csv format.

This is the script i am working which got from Microsoft Technet and i have modified to meet my requirement. Script is working as it should be but there is looping going on which i can't figure out how it should be stopped.

```
$ServersToQuery = Get-Content "C:\Users\metho.HOME\Desktop\computernames.txt"
$cred = "home\Administrator"
$StartTime = "September 19, 2018"
#$Yesterday = (Get-Date) - (New-TimeSpan -Days 1)


    foreach ($Server in $ServersToQuery) {

        $LogFilter = @{
            LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational'
            ID = 21, 23, 24, 25
            StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
            }

        $AllEntries = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $LogFilter -ComputerName $Server -Credential $cred

        $AllEntries | Foreach { 
            $entry = [xml]$_.ToXml()

            $Output += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                TimeCreated = $_.TimeCreated
                User = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.User
                IPAddress = $entry.Event.UserData.EventXML.Address
                EventID = $entry.Event.System.EventID
                ServerName = $Server
                }        
            } 

    }


    $FilteredOutput += $Output | Select TimeCreated, User, ServerName, IPAddress, @{Name='Action';Expression={
                if ($_.EventID -eq '21'){"logon"}
                if ($_.EventID -eq '22'){"Shell start"}
                if ($_.EventID -eq '23'){"logoff"}
                if ($_.EventID -eq '24'){"disconnected"}
                if ($_.EventID -eq '25'){"reconnection"}
                }
            }

    $Date = (Get-Date -Format s) -replace ":", "-"
    $FilePath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$Date`_RDP_Report.csv"
    $FilteredOutput | Sort TimeCreated | Export-Csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation

Write-host "Writing File: $FilePath" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Cyan


#End
```

First time when i run the script, it runs fine and i get the csv output as it should be. When i run the script again than a new CSV is created (as it should be) but the same event log enteries are created twice and run it again than three enteries are created for the same event. This is very strange as a new csv is created each time and i dont not have -append switch for export-csv configured.

```
$FilteredOutput = @()
$Output = @()
```

I did try adding these two lines in above script as i read somewhere that it is needed if i am mixing multiple variables into a array (i do not understand this so applogies if i get this wrong).

Can someone please help me this, more importantly, I need to understand this as it is good to know for my future projects.

Thanks agian.

mEtho

Comment: Is that script the entire script that you are running?

Comment: This is the entire script. do you think its incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the`$Output` and `$FilteredOutput` variables aren't getting cleared when you run the script subsequent times (nothing in the current script looks to do that), so the results are just getting appended to these variables each time.

As you've already said, you could add these to the top of your script:

```
$FilteredOutput = @()
$Output = @()
```

This will initialise them as empty arrays at the beginning, which will ensure they start empty as well as make it possible for them to be appended to (which happens at the script via `+=`). Without doing this on the first run the script likely failed, so I assume you must have done this in your current session at some point for it to be working at all.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for that. Sounds like this will resolve it. I have never tested it with those two variables being right at the top. Can you please explain how this process works as i am very much in needing to understand this so i dont repeat this again. thank you for your effort.

Comment: I am out just now. i will post the outcome in next half an hour. thanks again

Comment: Thats done Mark, Thank you for your answer. I need to spend some time understanding "@()" and also this open array that kept appanding stuff to it. Very strange but its working now. thanks